# Programmatically change display color/tint in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, windows-phone-8

Is there any way to change the display tint or color using the Windows Phone API? I'm looking for something similar to how F.lux changes the blue amount.

Comment: This seems to come up from time to time http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=f.lux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot. System settings cannot be changed by applications, they can only be changed by users.

If you want to enable it for your application only, that is possible. But globally, unlikely.